# Mysql generate big IO

Tags: mysql, io

Mysql begin generate big IO.

One website have many rows in session,requests table ( whan user enter to the site, app write info about him in table requests and session).
On site not used memcache or some like that.

How to config mysql_query_cache for optimize select of this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If it's not already done, you should add indexes to your session table : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization-indexes.html
- You should also add a cleaning mechanism to remove old and expired sessions data.
- You could also use an other session storage, i'm thinking about memcached or reddis for instance.